# android usb connection for android v <= 2.2

Tags: android, usb, linux-device-driver

I want to connect my android phone to my pc using USB cable.

Now, I need to send some messages to the pc from my android device via this USB connection ans vice a versa.

I know about USB host but sadly i am using android 2.2. My pc has linux so i can develop basic device driver.

I want to know,
Is there any other api for such task ? 
If not how should i approach it using device driver ? Which communication protocol should i use ?

P.S. :I am not talking about connecting other USB device. I just want to communicate using the cable provided with our phone.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you have sdk installed on the pc u can communicate via adb very easily.

Comment: this does not answer the question and should not be posted as one.